# Can you show/list all extended-attributes and how?

Tags: linux, file-attributes

Can you show/list all extended-attributes and how?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Linux, independent of filesystem command to view file extended attributes is

```
getfattr -d -m '' -- <filename>
```

At last it show Selinux attributes.

```
getfattr -d -- <filename>
```

Show only user.* attributes.

Comment: I'd suggest `getfattr -d -m ^ -R -- <filename or directory>`

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen why? Sorry, never used that before.

Comment: The `-m ^` matches start of any string without need for escaping the parameter and double dash `--` is needed as a separator in case the filename or directory starts with a dash.

Comment: This is technically not correct. Try using `getfattr` to list xattrs in the `system` namespace on an NTFS filesystem mounted via the ntfs-3g driver. Even as root they are not listed. However, one can get the value of the xattr, eg. `system.ntfs_acl`, if specifying the name of the xattr explicitly via the `-n` parameter. I've yet to see a way to have the `system` xattrs listed.

Comment: `getfattr -d -m '' <filename or directory>` also appears to list all xattrs, as an empty regex matches every string.

Answer (score 4):

On a MacOs the Unix flavor is Darwin which is derived from BSD. In this version of Unix, use the command `xattr` to list (or create, write, or clear) the extended attributes.

`xattr <filename>` will just list the names of the attributes

`xattr -l <filename>` will list their names and values

`xattr -h` for a more succinct help message

`man xattr` for a detailed help message (`ZZ` to exit the help)

I found this command at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes#macOS

Answer (score 3):

getfattr is not present in my debian distribution. I use this instead:

```
lsattr <filename>
```

Comment: That is different attributes.  "lsattr" lists "file attributes" which is a specific set of attributes available on ext* file systems.  "getfattr" lists "extended attributes" which is a kind of name-value pairs available on several file systems.  See the respective manual pages for details.

Comment: This is misleading. The `getfattr` command is an official part of Ubuntu, and presumably Debian, but is in the `attr` package, which is not installed by default.  Use `apt install attr` to get it. And it is indeed different than `lsattr` as noted by Göran.

Comment: `I-node flags (ext2 extended file attributes)` is derived from the `ext2` file system, but nowadays it is also available on other file systems. A minor supplement to @GöranUddeborg's comment.

Answer (score -1):

The command to list all extended attributes is `ls -l@`.

An example (from my mac, linux/BSD will look different):

```
felixphew-mbp:/ felixphew$ ls -l@
total 45
drwxrwxr-x+ 63 root  admin  2142 27 Dec 17:49 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 62 root  wheel  2108 16 Nov 06:25 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root  wheel    68 10 Sep 06:47 Network
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x+  4 root  wheel   136  1 Nov 14:02 System
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin   204 28 Dec 07:36 Users
drwxrwxrwt@  3 root  admin   102 30 Dec 06:40 Volumes
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 39 root  wheel  1326 11 Nov 07:06 bin
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxrwxr-t@  2 root  admin    68 10 Sep 06:47 cores
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  4306 30 Dec 06:40 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Nov 13:56 etc -> private/etc
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 30 Dec 06:40 home
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   313  1 Oct 16:12 installer.failurerequests
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 30 Dec 06:40 net
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel   102 12 Aug 07:19 opt
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel   204  1 Nov 14:05 private
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 59 root  wheel  2006 18 Nov 07:46 sbin
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel   102 22 Dec 07:46 srv
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Nov 13:57 tmp -> private/tmp
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 root  wheel   442 23 Nov 11:20 usr
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32 
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Nov 13:57 var -> private/var
    com.apple.FinderInfo      32
```

The same dir in `ls -l`:

```
felixphew-mbp:/ felixphew$ ls -l
total 45
drwxrwxr-x+ 63 root  admin  2142 27 Dec 17:49 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 62 root  wheel  2108 16 Nov 06:25 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root  wheel    68 10 Sep 06:47 Network
drwxr-xr-x+  4 root  wheel   136  1 Nov 14:02 System
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin   204 28 Dec 07:36 Users
drwxrwxrwt@  3 root  admin   102 30 Dec 06:40 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 39 root  wheel  1326 11 Nov 07:06 bin
drwxrwxr-t@  2 root  admin    68 10 Sep 06:47 cores
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  4306 30 Dec 06:40 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Nov 13:56 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 30 Dec 06:40 home
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   313  1 Oct 16:12 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 30 Dec 06:40 net
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel   102 12 Aug 07:19 opt
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel   204  1 Nov 14:05 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 59 root  wheel  2006 18 Nov 07:46 sbin
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel   102 22 Dec 07:46 srv
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Nov 13:57 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 root  wheel   442 23 Nov 11:20 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11  1 Nov 13:57 var -> private/var
```

Comment: The `@` argument given to `ls` is an `invalid option` on linux. I looked up the `@` option and this is specific to mac OS-X. This question is specific to linux.

Comment: Glad to know the option `@` on macOS, thank you.